# Get-Unique returns incorrect results

Tags: powershell

In this PowerShell command to find the owners of files in a folder,

```
Get-ChildItem $dir -Recurse | foreach {Get-Acl $_.fullname | select owner} | Get-Unique -AsString
```

`Get-Unique` returns every result that is different from the one before it instead of checking the whole list. For example:

```
   domain\user1
   domain\user2
   domain\user1
   domain\user3
   domain\user1
```

It should return only one of each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `Get-Help Get-Unique`

> The Get-Unique cmdlet compares each item in a sorted list to the next item, eliminates duplicates, and returns only one instance of each item. **The list must be sorted for the cmdlet to work properly.**

To get the result you want, pipe your list through `Sort-Object` prior to using `Get-Unique`

```
$list | sort | Get-Unique
```

This behavior is the same as the [`uniq`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/uniq) command in Unix.

Comment: Thank you. However, I found you do have to sort on property like: `$list | sort -property owner | get-unique`

Comment: Actually, you don't need to do that if you modify your `Get-Acl` block to use `select -ExpandProperty owner`.  That gives you just the owner, rather than an object with an owner property.